# Select rows of a data frame based on a vector containing several strings

Tags: r, string, grepl

I have a vector of words that I need to use it to select several rows in a data frame with more than 1000 observations. I will put a simple one below.

These are the foods I have to looking for in the data frame:`ls_foods <- c("Abacate", "Abacaxi",  "Abóbora", "Abobrinha", "Acelga",  "Acerola", "Alface", "Almeirão", "Arroz", "Banana", "Batata", "Batata doce", "Berinjela","Brocolis","Cacau", "Café")`

This is the df. I have to select only the rows containing the words in the vector `ls_foods`. Some of them contains special characters and others not.

```
id <- (1:5)
Variables <- c("abacate - kg", "batata inglesa - Kg", "Pera - pés", "Brocolis - Kg", "Laranja (Lima, Pêra, da Terra, etc) - Pés")
df <- data.frame(id, variables)
```

I tried this, but without success:

```
df <- df[grepl(ls_foods, df$desc_var)]
```

The result I would expect is:

```
id <- c(1, 2,4)
Variables <- c("abacate - kg", "batata inglesa - Kg", "Brocolis - Kg")
df_1 <- data.frame(id, variables)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but perhaps you want `est_1km[est_1km$desc_var %in% ls_alimento, ]`.

Comment: I've tried this too. Maybe I can try a ´´´loop`´´, but I'm not very good at it.

Comment: The question is clearer after your edit. Indeed, my comment was not the right way.

Comment: You can try this, `grepl(paste0(ls_foods, collapse="|"), df$desc_var) `

Comment: If you don't put a comma in `[` for a data frame, it will default to columns. You want rows. So try `df <- df[grepl(paste0(ls_foods, collapse="|"), df$desc_var), ]`, which both adds the needed comma and concatenates the pattern with `|` for OR.

Comment: Thanks, it worked =)

Answer (score 2):

Try `subset` + `grepl` like below

```
subset(
  df,
  grepl(
    paste0(ls_foods, collapse = "|"),
    variables,
    ignore.case = TRUE
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  id           variables
1  1        abacate - kg
2  2 batata inglesa - Kg
4  4       Brocolis - Kg
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my answer, check that I'm using a line to convert special characters in non-so-special characters, there you have to specify what special chars are like to appear.

```
id <- (1:5)
variables <- c("abacate - kg", "batata inglesa - Kg", "Pera - pés", 
               "Brocolis - Kg", "Laranja (Lima, Pêra, da Terra, etc) - Pés")
df <- data.frame(id, variables)


ls_foods <- c("Abacate", "Abacaxi",  "Abóbora", "Abobrinha", "Acelga",  
              "Acerola", "Alface", "Almeirão", "Arroz", "Banana", "Batata", 
              "Batata doce", "Berinjela","Brocolis","Cacau", "Café")

# Convert special characters with chartr
answer <- unlist(sapply(chartr(old = "áéíóúàèìòù", new = "aeiouaeiou", x = tolower(ls_foods)), 
                 grep, x = tolower(variables)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally when handling accented characters where the accent is not treated as meaningful, I simplify everything to Latin ASCII. The `stringi` package is convenient for this.

```
library(stringi)

simplify <- function(x) stri_trans_general(x, "Latin-ASCII; Lower"))

df[
  stri_detect_regex(
    simplify(df$variables),
    paste(simplify(ls_foods), collapse = "|")
  ),
]
```